# excute JavaScript Function from Native after Worklight Init

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I developed an Android Service to wake up an Android application (based on Worklight). after the application starts up, I have to execute a JavaScript Function.
this is what I did :

WebView.loadUrl("javascript:getFirstPosition()");

The problem is that the JavaScript Function is executed before the WebView is loaded.
So I need to set an event listener like "onPageLoaded" to handle this event and execute my function at this time.
any idea about how to do that form android native context ?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by delaying the JavaScript function's call , this is how I did :

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
             scheduleTaskExecutor.schedule(new Runnable() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void run () {
                                    // execute Worklight Trigger function and start up acquisition process
                                     WebView.loadUrl("javascript:getFirstPosition()");().getString(BROADCAST_TAG)+")");
                                 }
                                }, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished

It might be what you're looking for (although I do not understand the use case)

Comment: Thanks @Anton, I tried this function :super.webViewClient.onPageFinished(arg0, arg1)  on the "onCreate" but nothing happen , even the javascript function is not called.

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand, you need listener to callback you when WebView is loaded.

Try with this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Your code here
}
```

Maybe this can help you: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html